# I am getting error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get', and I can't quite figure out how to solve said problem

Tags: python, tkinter, nonetype

I am writing code that asks for a numerical input through Tkinter. Where that is going to be used as a perimeter in a loop that carries out the function of rolling two dice. I am getting error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get', and I can't quite figure out how to solve said problem.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk() 

numlist = []

question = Label(root, text = "how many times do you want to roll the two dice? : ").pack()

def myClick():

    value = e.get() + 0
    return int(value)
    for u in range(value):                                                           
     numlist.append(random.randint(1,6)+random.randint(1,6))  
    print(dict((r, numlist.count(r) ) for r in sorted(numlist)))

e = Entry(root, width=50).pack()


B_Enter = Button(root, text="Enter", command=myClick).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ``Event.pack`` returns ``None``. As a rule of thumb, methods that mutate their object generally do not return said object in Python.

Comment: The error means that you tried to call `get` from an object with a value of `None`.  The only place you do that is `value = e.get() + 0`; therefore `e` is `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lose the reference to the `Entry` because `e` is set to the output of the `pack()` function, which returns `None` after giving the entry to the geography packer.

To get the correct reference to  the `Entry` in `e`, separate the `.pack()` command to a separate line, e.g.:

```
   e = Entry(root, width=50)
   e.pack()
```